# Replace and increment a line in bash

Tags: text-processing, scripting, numeric-data

How can I read, increment and replace a value in a file?

```
foo="val"
ver="1.2.0001"
...
```

Now I would like to increment the "0001" to 0002".

Comment: What should happen when it reaches 9999?  Also, note that bash is not a text editor.

Comment: nothing, could increment to 10000.

Comment: Is the "0001" identified by "0001" or as being the 3rd element of the "ver" string?

Comment: 3rd element can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the patch level is always going to be a string of four digits:

```
$ ver=1.2.0001
$ printf '%s\n' "$ver" | awk -F '.' '{ printf("%s.%s.%04d\n", $1, $2, $3 + 1) }'
1.2.0002
```

This uses `awk` and treats the version as three fields delimited by dots.  It prints the first two fields as they are, but adds 1 to the third field and formats the result using `%04d` (a zero-filled, four digit, decimal number).

This would generate `1.2.10000` if `$ver` was `1.2.9999`.

To store the value back into `ver`, use `ver=$( printf ... | awk ... )`.

Comment: ended up with the following code
`infofile=./buildinfo.txt
version=$(cat $infofile | grep "version" | awk -F'"' '{ print $2 }'  )
version=$(echo $version | awk -F '.' '{ printf("%s.%s.%04d", $1, $2, $3 + 1 ) }')
echo -e Current  BuildVersion=$version
sed -i "s/version=.*/version=\"$version\"/" $infofile`

Comment: @robb30 If you had given a bit of context to what it was you were doing, we would have given you a much less complicated solution than that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `perl`, which is a pretty powerful text manipulator:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(^ver="\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)"/"$1.$2." . sprintf("%04d", $3+1) . "\""/e' input
```

This invokes perl with three options:

- `-p` -- auto-print each line of input
- `-i` -- edit the file in-place
- `-e` -- use the next argument as the code to execute

The code says to do a search & replacement on every line of input; the "search" part will only match lines that:

1. begin with `ver="`
2. followed by one or more digits (`\d+` means "match digit, one or more times")
3. followed by a period `.`, which has to be escaped for regex rules
4. followed by one or more non-period characters
5. followed by a period `.`
6. followed by one or more non-period characters
7. followed by a double-quote

Items #1 and #2 are grouped together in parentheses as replacement text `$1`; item #4 is replacement text `$2`, and item #6 becomes replacement text $3. Before putting `$3` back in place, though, we send it through a formatted print statement that adds one to the value.

Because we need to execute perl code in the replacement, we need the `e` option at the end of the `s///`. We also have to add back in the trailing double-quote, which was required as item #7.

You could tighten or loosen this regular expression in various ways; perhaps you could require that the matching "ver" string be the only thing on the line, in which case you would add `$` end-of-line anchor after the double-quote in item #7.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately no perl avaiable on this machine.

Comment: @robb30 please remember to always mention your operating system so we can know what's available. The vast majority of *nix systems have perl, for example.

Answer (score 0):

With `bash`:

```
$ ver="1.2.0001"
$ printf -v ver '%s.%04d' "${ver%.*}" "$((${ver##*.} + 1))"
$ echo "$ver"
1.2.0002
```

- `${ver%.*}` is used to get the prefix `1.2` removing suffix pattern `.*`
- `${ver##*.}` is used to get the number portion `0001` removing the longest prefix pattern `*.`
- `printf -v ver ...` prints the prefix plus `.` and the incremented number using bash arithmetics `$((... + 1))` and saves the output back into variable `ver`.